# Visual Studio - Working on the same project via multiple machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I like to work between my laptop and desktop during different parts of the day.
I have recently installed VS 2010 Ultimate (Extreme) and am wondering the best way to go about sharing a project across these two machines.
Whether to go with something like subversion, or whether to put the project on a network drive and open it on the current machine I am on.
Any thoughts or warnings from someone more experienced much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get VS 2010 Extreme from given that this DOES NOT EXIST?

Comment: ^^ He must be referring to the Ultimate version, I think.

Comment: That must be one very expensive MSDN subscription you have there.

Comment: Yep sorry, all these names. Ultimate is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would most certainly go with Subversion or Git.

I have a work & home desktop + a laptop on which I do all my dev work.

I save all my changes to Subversion (which in itself is good practise) and it also means that I can carry on from where I left off really fast.. A quick Update command gets my latest code and I'm ready to go..

Also, to save me from having to copy databases or run database projects, I run my DBs on my work PC (which I never turn off) and access it via VPN. There's no need to change connection strings in my apps either since My-PC\SQLEXPRESS works both from My-PC and from the other 2 computers (because they're on the same network).

Comment: Thanks Marko, Ultimately having a machine you don't turn off is the way to go, I guess.

Comment: well thats only for the DB, I run svn at Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server on an accessible networked that gets backed up, use that along with a source control app.

Comment: Thanks, when you say 'source control app' you are referring to something like svn or git right?

Comment: Yes, or one of the Microsoft products if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chance, install TFS.
Now TFS can be installed on a desktop machine with Windows 7 or xp

With TFS you will maximize your distributed works. Visual Studio has best entegration with TFS.

I suggest you to use TFS; if you have a licenced copy or MSDN subs.